# Add CRLF on a C string on declaration

Tags: c, string, newline

Let

```
const char cstring[] = "cstringline";
```

How can the above code be altered, to append CRLF in compile time aka declaration?

Comment: Either your answer is: by putting a `\n` at the end of your string, or I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: This would be mentioned in any C tutorial. Did you make the effort reading one?

Comment: Yes, that was the correct way but it needed \r\n.

Comment: @H2CO3 I've seen some pretty horrible C tutorials... In fact, I've found that "tutorial" authors are quite possibly the least humble, and have the least expertise. Humility is a requirement in the IT industry, because one must first recognise change before adapting to it, and there are few "tutorial" authors who seem to have humility. They probably see alterior motives to assuming the position of an "expert".

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Yes, but there are good ones as well - and one can read them as well, in my opinion.

Comment: @H2CO3 I've found far more horrible tutorials than I have horrible books on this subject. While I agree that both can be fantastic (for the same reasons), and both can be horrible (for the same reasons), books tend to be revised more thoroughly than tutorials. I'd suggest this is because *anyone can publish a tutorial*, whilst not just anyone can publish a book. A *nobody* won't necessarily see any benefit to correcting errors (and will often try to fight against it in order to establish a reputable image), whilst a professor's reputation is on the line if he/she doesn't correct errors.

Comment: Actually, I found this very useful just now. I was adding CR LF at the end of a line and it wasn't behaving as it should. I Googled it, this was the first hit and it solved my issue. People should be a little slower to be so critical of people trying to learn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unix line ending:

```
const char str[] = "foobarbaz\n";
```

Legacy Mac line ending:

```
const char str[] = "foobarbaz\r";
```

Windows line ending:

```
const char str[] = "foobarbaz\r\n";
```

(But really, google...)

Comment: Indeed, there is a CRLF ("\r\n") in the third example. When writing to stdout or any other file that is open as a text stream, the implementation will translate from '\n' to the native line terminator; '\n' translates to '\r' in pre-MacOSX OSes and "\r\n" in Windows.

Comment: POSIX requires text mode and binary mode to be identical, so sometimes you really do need to do these manually, e.g. if you're writing Windows text files from unix or from a POSIX enviroment (e.g. cygwin) on Windows. And some people just prefer to use binary mode all the time because text mode is so ill-specified and ill-behaved with respect to seeking and file position. BTW, you also need CRLF to conform to some internet protocols, where the format is dictated by the protocol and not your own system's line end convention.

Comment: By the way, you got those wrong. DOS and Windows are the same, `\r\n`. Only legacy Mac (pre-OSX) uses lone `\r`. Modern Mac uses Unix line endings, and modern Windows supports Unix line endings (files with just `\n` will get loaded perfectly fine, but `\r` might get added when they're resaved.

Comment: @R.. I know `\r` is pre-OS X, but I thought DOS used `\r` as well. Could you pleas cite some reference?

Comment: I thought it would be obvious; the whole point of all the backwards stuff Windows does was to be DOS-compatible. I also have plenty of experience using DOS. As for references, the unix tools to convert are called `dos2unix` and `unix2dos`, and the format they convert from/to is CRLF. If that's not enough, just ask [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: I doubt we'd be in this predicament if line printers hadn't been invented.